# Use foreach (pgf) in an itemize environment with sagetex

Tags: itemize, foreach, sagetex

I want to generate calculations randomly using sagetex, trying to have the simplest code possible. I ended up testing this, with `pgf` :

```
\begin{sagesilent}
from random import sample
def alea(n, max):
    complete_list = [Integer(i) for i in range(-max, max+1, 1) if i != 0 and i != -1 and i != 1]
    list = sample(complete_list, n)
    return(list)
def somme(a):
    f1 = a[0]/a[1]
    f2 = a[2]/a[3]
    somme = f1+f2
    return [f1, f2, somme]
\end{sagesilent}

\begin{sagesilent}a = alea(4, 15)\end{sagesilent}

\begin{enumerate}
\foreach \n in {0,...,5}{\item $\displaystyle\sage{somme(a)[0]}+\sage{somme(a)[1]}=\sage{somme(a)[2]}$}
\end{enumerate}
```

It's interesting but of course, I have 5 times the same operation, so I tried :

```
\begin{enumerate}
\foreach \n in {0,...,5}{\item \begin{sagesilent}a = alea(4, 15)\end{sagesilent}$\displaystyle\sage{somme(a)[0]}+\sage{somme(a)[1]}=\sage{somme(a)[2]}$}
\end{enumerate}
```

but it returned :

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
<inserted text> 
\par
```

I don't understand how to fix the error (I compil with lualatex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not unusual for packages to conflict. The [sagetex](https://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex?lang=en) document talks about problems working with `Beamer` and `rcol` packages on pages 14-15. Perhaps one of the wizards here can figure out the problem but that's beyond me. I can, however, answer your question of "how to fix the error " with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
max = 15
complete_list = [Integer(i) for i in range(-max, max+1, 1) if i != 0 and i != -1 and i != 1]

from random import sample
def alea(n, complete_list):
    return(sample(complete_list, n))

def somme(a):
    f1 = a[0]/a[1]
    f2 = a[2]/a[3]
    somme = f1+f2
    return [f1, f2, somme]

output = r"\begin{enumerate}"
for i in range(6):
    a = alea(4,complete_list)
    output += r"\item $\displaystyle %s+\left(%s\right)=%s$"%(latex(somme(a)[0]),latex(somme(a)[1]),latex(somme(a)[2]))
output += r"\end{enumerate}"
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{output}
\end{document}
```

The result in Cocalc is shown below:
[image]

With respect to the code changes:
First, you have function `alea` creating `complete_list` every time you call it, so I defined it first based on what you want `max` to be. That means `complete_list` is created once rather than 6 times. Second, there is no reason to create a variable `list` and return it, when you can just return `sample(complete_list, n)`. Third, it is frequently easiest to do the work strictly in Python as a string and insert it into the document on the third pass of the LaTeX/Python/LaTeX way the document is processed. I've used `raw` strings, which can handle symbols such as `\` without problems, to create the `enumerate` environment code. It is copied into the .tex file with `\sagestr`.  Finally, you are allowing negative rational numbers so I've put parenthesis around the second number to avoid having `+-` together in the output.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I had actually thought about doing something like this, but was hoping the other way can be fixed. Your remarks greatly improve the code, I had previously tested something like : somme_reponse_ltx += r"\item $\displaystyle{} + \left(\displaystyle{}\right)=\displaystyle{}$".format(latex(f1), latex(f2), latex(somme)). In fact, I try to write the subjects without the results, and write the results below, out of order. I made this program in python, which I launched in my latex document (it worked well) then I discovered sage... your answer will help me for sure.